# How to properly use SortedDictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, sorting, sorteddictionary

I'm trying to do something very simple but it seems that I don't understand `SortedDictionary`.

What I'm trying to do is the following:
Create a sorted dictionary that sorts my items by some floating number, so I create a dictionary that looks like this

```
SortedDictionary<float, Node<T>> allNodes = new SortedDictionary<float, Node<T>>();
```

And now after I add items, I want to remove them one by one (every removal should be at a complexity of O(log(n)) from the smallest to the largest.

How do I do it? I thought that simply `allNodes[0]` will give me the the smallest, but it doesn't.

More over, it seems like the dictionary can't handle duplicate keys. I feel like I'm using the wrong data structure...
Should I use something else if I have bunch of nodes that I want to be sorted by their distance (floating point)?

Comment: Dictionary Key values have to be unique. I think you want to use a List<Node<T>> instead since Lists can have duplicate entries. Then use LINQ to manipulate the data into the order you want them to be in.

Comment: Do you just want to sort a collection of nodes based on some value each node has, or is there some particular reason you need to use a `SortedDictionary`?  If the former, just use the LINQ `OrderBy` on whatever the collection was when you started.

Comment: I want to insert and remove in O(Log(n)), most of my job is insert and remove... which list does in O(N). and to your question : the sort is based on some value in each node.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`allNodes[0]` will not give you the first item in the dictionary - it will give you the item with a `float` *key value* of `0`.

If you want the first item try `allNodes.Values.First()` instead.  Or to find the first *key* use `allNodes.Keys.First()`

To *remove* the items one by one, loop over a *copy* of the `Keys` collection and call `allNodes.Remove(key);`

```
foreach (var key in allNodes.Keys.ToList())
{
    allNodes.Remove(key);
}
```

To answer your addendum to your question, yes `SortedDictionary` (any flavor of `Dictionary` for that matter) will not handle duplicate keys - if you try and add an item with an existing key it will *overwrite* the previous value.

You could use a `SortedDictionary<float, List<Node<T>>>` but then you have the complexity of extracting *collections* versus items, needing to *initialize* each list rather than just adding an item, etc.  It's all possible and may still be the fastest structure for adds and gets, but it does add a bit of complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right about complexity.

In `SortedDictionary` all the keys are sorted. If you want to iterate from the smallest to the largest, `foreach` will be enough:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<float, Node<T>> kvp in allNodes)
{
    // Do Something...
}
```

You wrote that you want to remove items. It's forbidden to remove from collections during iteratation with `foreach`, so firstly create a copy of it to do so.

EDIT:

Yes, if you have duplicated keys you can't use `SortedDictionary`. Create a structural Node with `Node<T>` and `float`, then write a comparer:

```
public class NodeComparer : IComparer<Node>
{
    public int Compare(Node n1, Node n2)
    {
        return n2.dist.CompareTo(n1.dist);
    }
}
```

And then put everything in simple `List<Node> allNodes` and sort:

```
allNodes.Sort(new NodeComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

As a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` must have unique keys, I'd use `List<Node<T>>` instead. For instance, if your `Node<T>` class has a `Value` property

```
class Node<T>
{
    float Value { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

and you want to sort by this property, use LINQ:

```
var list = new List<Node<T>>();

// populate list

var smallest = list.OrderBy(n => n.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

To remove the nodes one by one, just iterate threw the list:

```
while (list.Count > 0)
{
    list.RemoveAt(0);
}
```